# declare raml data type with array of different objects

Tags: arrays, types, raml

I have two different `Datatypes` (this collection can grow and can have more types):

```
#%RAML 1.0 DataType

type: object
properties:
  sftp:
    type: object
    properties:
      directory: 
        type: string
        example: /upload
      host: 
        type: string
        example: 223.198.120.125
      port: 
        type: string
        example: "2222"
      user: 
        type: string
        example: foo
      pass: 
        type: string
        example: pass
```

```
#%RAML 1.0 DataType

type: object
properties:
  file:
    type: object
    properties:
      path: 
        type: string
        example: /mule/inbound
```

I wish I could define both of them as elements of another `Datatype`, such as the input JSON could be like:

```
{
   "alarms":[
      {
         "sftp":{
            "directory":"/upload",
            "host":"223.198.120.125",
            "port":"2222",
            "user":"foo",
            "pass":"pass"
         }
      },
      {
         "file":{
            "path":"/mule/inbound"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

I tried Anurag answer but got:

```
{
  "sftp": {
    "sftp": {
      "directory": "/upload",
      "host": "223.198.120.125",
      "port": "2222",
      "user": "foo",
      "pass": "pass"
    }
  },
  "file": {
    "file": {
      "directory": "/mule/inbound"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: do you want to include both data types as in another RAML file, so that can be relate to your o/p?

Comment: @AnuragSharma yes

Comment: I have edited my answer to add sftp and file in to alarms, But its not adding both sftp and file at different indexes of Alarms array. its a lil it tricky. I am figuring out it, will update soon!! in mean could you please edit your question with the o/p that you will get now from my answer ?

Answer (score 0):

I have created 3 RAML files with your DataType input in question

1. The first DataType input mentioned in your question is saved as data2.raml
2. The second DataType input mentioned in your question is saved as data3.raml
3. crated another DataType named as data.raml and added both above RAML into this as elements that correlate with your input JSON mentioned in the question

**data.raml file is as below:**

```
#%RAML 1.0 DataType

type: object
properties:
  alarms: 
    type: array
    items: [!include data2.raml,!include data3.raml]
```

4. all 3 RAML files are kept inside a **folder called types**
5. crated an examples folder and inside created a file with the name "data.json" that you can use as output or input. I didn't include it (as you were doing (motioned in the comment))
6. created a main RAML file with resource name /notification that will use all three data type files as below

```
#RAML 1.0
title: test raml
version: v1
protocols: [HTTPS]

types:
    testdata:
        type: !include types/data.raml
        
/notifications:
  post:
    body:
      application/json:
        type: testdata
              
    responses:
        200:
           body:
              application/json:
                example: !include examples/data.json
```

below is the snippet of these folder structures

[image]

Comment: Anurag, thanks for your answer! I tried it without adding the type .json example to check how design center would structure. I put the output I got on my question.

Comment: you mean you tried by directly putting your output json in example: instead of using from file? and it didnt give you o/p

Comment: I didnt add any example on design center. on my op I just added how I expected it to generate the output json

Comment: I have edited my answer but its not adding both sftp and file at different indexes of Alarms array. its a lil it tricky. I am figuring out it, will update soon!!

Comment: updated my answer , including the example now in  the response. Also working on how to add both sftp and file at different indexes of alarm array.